# GemBox Excel Load Issue - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gembox-spreadsheet

I'm using GemBox to disable the grid lines of a Bulk Excel Export I'm trying to do from my ASP.Net MVC application. Out of many sheets, for a few sheets, however, I'm getting `Input string was not in a correct format` error. One thing to note is that the issue is not recurring, sometimes it passes as well. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Also, how do I check if  the input stream is correct or not before passing it to the `Load()`? Is there any way?

Below is my code snippet:

```
private static Stream DisableGridLinesInGemBoxExcel(Stream inputStream) 
    {
            ExcelFile workbookOriginal = ExcelFile.Load(inputStream); // this line throws an error
            var workbookNew = new ExcelFile();

            foreach (var worksheet in workbookOriginal.Worksheets)
            {
                worksheet.ViewOptions.ShowGridLines = false;
                workbookNew.Worksheets.AddCopy(worksheet.Name, worksheet);
            }

            Stream resultStream = new MemoryStream();
            workbookNew.Save(resultStream, GemBox.Spreadsheet.SaveOptions.XlsxDefault);
            return resultStream;
    }
```

[image]

**Additional Note:**
I came across a similar issue with GemBox PDF in the GemBox support page - [Random occurrence of “Input string was not in a correct format.” when loading a PDF document](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2699178/mario-z)

Comment: Can you upload that input file somewhere so that I can reproduce your issue and investigate it? Also, what version of GemBox.Spreadsheet are you using?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2699178/mario-z apologies, I won't be able to upload the file because it contains sensitive data..all I can say is that the issue is not recurring, sometimes, it passes as well which is kind of weird..also, I'm using v47.0.1418 of GemBox.Spreadsheet

Comment: In that case, you should consider sending a small Visual Studio project that reproduces the issue on [GemBox support](https://support.gemboxsoftware.com/new-ticket).

Comment: Okay @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2699178/mario-z, I will do so. Meanwhile, I came across a similar issue with with GemBox PDF in the GemBox Support page itself - https://forum.gemboxsoftware.com/t/random-occurrence-of-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-when-loading-a-pdf-document/484

Comment: As you may notice, that issue was resolved after the input file was provided. Unfortunately, there is no other way to fix this without investigating the file, the problem is specific to the input file and thus requires it for troubleshooting.